# Seleccione el nombre de las ciudades por arriba del promedio de todas las ciudades en SQL?

Tags: sql, mariadb

Como se escribiria esta consulta en SQL?
se podria hacer con

```
select avg(poblacion) from city;
```

y que mas?, no tengo idea de como hacerlo...
Utilizo XAMPP.
**version()
10.4.14-MariaDB**

[image: Esta es la estructura de mi Tabla]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes:

- Tu consulta esta *correcta*, pero es parte de algo mas grande, notarás en el resultado que es de hecho la query que va en el cuerpo de la subconsulta
- Primero eliges la columna de ciudad, entonces debes hacer un filtro por medio de un `where`
- En el filtro mencionado, vas a indicar que solo retorne las ciudades cuya población sea mayor a....
- Para completar el filtro anterior, debes construir una subconsulta en la cual indicarás que te calcule el promedio de población de todas las ciudades
- Solo cuando la condición anterior resulte cierta (*que el valor de la población sea mayor al promedio general*) entonces te devolverá ciudades

Consulta:

```
SELECT Name
FROM city
WHERE Population > (SELECT AVG(Population) from city);
```

**Referencias**

- [subconsultas](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/subqueries/)
- [where](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/select/)
- Aunque estás trabajando con MariaDB, te anexo también la [documentación de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subqueries.html) la cual también te ayudará a comprender mejor el tema de subconsulta y dicho conocimiento es portable a tu ejercicio actual.

Comment: Gracias, me ayudo mucho.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select name from city
Where population > (select 
avg(population) from city;
```

Lo que se hace es una consulta dentro del where que devuelve el promedio de todas las ciudades y este resultado es el que se compara con el campo population de la consulta general. Importante la consulta dentro del where solo debe devolver un campo que en este caso es el promedio de todas las ciudades

Answer (score 1):

Si deseas obtener las ciudades que tienen arriba del promedio de población puedes realizarlo de la siguiente manera, incluso puedes ordenar los valores de forma descendente.

```
select * from city  where  Population > (SELECT AVG(Population) FROM City) order by Population DESC
```

Aquí puedes realizar una simulación de la consulta

https://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master-config/index.php?route=/database/sql&db=world

Answer (score 0):

La consulta `Select avg("Population") from city`, te permite calcular el promedio poblacional de las ciudades que tienes en la tabla `city`, luego con el `Select` externo, puedes obtener los nombres de las ciudades cuyo valor poblacional sea mayor que el promedio.

```
Select "Name" from  city Where "Population">(Select avg("Population") from city);
```

Comment: Hola! Estaría bien que le explicases al OP que está haciendo el código, aunque para ti parezca sencillo, puede que otros no lo sepan :)